# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 for API 19 and below

Tags: android, android-asynctask

It only happens when the API 19 or below. I've comment in the necessary places. Mainly two error causes

1. ExceptionInInitializerError
2. IllegalStateException

The coding of main activity:-

```
public class MainActivity_Second extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {

    View v;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public static String TITLE = "title";
    public static String TIME = "time";
    public static String LIVE = "live";
    public static String LANGUAGE = "language";
    public static String LOCATION = "location";
    //static String FLAG = "flag";

    // URL Address
    String url = "url_address.html";

    public MainActivity_Second(){

    }

    //Internet connection checking
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(null);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_activity__second, container, false);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //Hiding and show the floating button
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                    fab.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    fab.hide();
                }
            });
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    new JsoupListView().execute();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity_Second.this.getActivity(), "No internet connection. Please check the connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new JsoupListView().execute();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    // Title AsyncTask
    private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //doInBackground Starts here
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            try {
                // Connect to the Website URL
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
                for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=ongoingclasses]")) {

                    // Identify all the table row's(tr)
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // Identify all the table cell's(td)
                        Elements tds = row.select("td");

                        // Retrive Jsoup Elements
                        // Get the first td
                        map.put("title", tds.get(0).text());
                        // Get the second td
                        map.put("time", tds.get(1).text());
                        // Get the third td
                        map.put("live", tds.get(2).text());

                        map.put("language", tds.get(3).text());

                        map.put("location", tds.get(4).text());
                        // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            try {
                // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
                listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity_Second.this.getActivity(), arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    listview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
                }

                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                    listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                            fab.show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                            fab.hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity_Second.this.getActivity(), "No internet connection. Please check the connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error log which I got

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.aocproject.mmfahrymohammed.aocproject, PID: 6457
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing 
doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.a.c.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.a.c.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.a.d.m.b(Unknown Source)
at org.a.d.m.a(Unknown Source)
at org.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
at org.a.d.g.a(Unknown Source)
at org.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
at org.a.a.c$c.e(Unknown Source)
at org.a.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aocproject.b.b$a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aocproject.b.b$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read resource entities-xhtml.properties. Make sure you copy resources for org.a.c.i
at org.a.c.i.b(Unknown Source)
at org.a.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
at org.a.c.i$b.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.a.c.i$b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.a.c.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.c.f.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.d.m.b(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.d.m.a(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.d.g.a(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.a.c$c.e(Unknown Source) 
at org.a.a.c.a(Unknown Source) 
at com.aocproject.b.b$a.a(Unknown Source) 
at com.aocproject.b.b$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: I can't find the reason about crash exactly because backtrace information is obfuscated. I think you used library about `Jsoup`, right? If you did, go to provider site to find manual and check about `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: Yes, I've used Jsoup 1.10.3. it works fine for above 19. I'll check it out.

Comment: Hi, I fixed this myself by configuring ProGuard rules. By adding this line `-keepnames class org.jsoup.nodes.Entities` or `-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}`

Btw `-keepnames class org.jsoup.nodes.Entities` is enough without any addition. Hope it helps to someone.